# New to TeX; issue with compiling

Tags: math-mode, errors, fractions

I keep getting the compiling error >file ended while scanning use of \frac.  I can't see any missing {}, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

Molar Mass of Nitrogen
\begin{math}
\\ Bulb Volume: 213.7 cm^{3} = .2317 L
\\ Internal bulb pressure: 20 inHg = 508 mmHg = .508 bar
\\ Temperature: 294.2 K
\\ M = \frac{\rho}{P}RT
\\ \rho = \frac{.158 g}{.2137 L} = .739\frac{g}{L}
\\ M = \frac{.739 \frac{g}{L}}{.508 bar} * .083144 \frac{L*bar}{mol*K} * 294.2 K = 35.6 \frac{g}{mol}

\\ Calculation of Volume by van der Waals Equation with Successive Approximations
\\ V = \frac{nRT}{P + \frac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}} + nb
\\ a = 1.408 \frac{L^{2}*bar}{mol^{2}}
b = .03913 L
\\ V \approx \frac{nRT}{P} + nb \approx \frac{nRT}{P}
\\ n = \frac{m}{M} = \frac{.158 g}{21.35 \frac{g}{mol}} = 7.4*10^{-3} mol
\\ V = \frac{7.4*10^{-3} mol * .083144 \frac{L*bar}{mol*K} * 294.2 K}{.508 bar} = .2138 L
\\ V = \frac{7.4*10^{-3} mol * .083144 \frac{L*bar}{mol*K} * 294.2 K}{.508 bar 
       + \frac{(7.4*10^{-3} mol)^{2}*1.408 \frac{L^{2}*bar}{mol^{2}}} {(.2138 L)^{2}} 
       + 7.4*10^{-3} mol * .03913 L = .2137 L
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

This is for a calculations addendum to an undergraduate chemistry lab.  I figured it would be worth the time investment to learn laTeX.  It's already significantly faster to do calculations in it than word, if only I can get around these compiling errors.

Relevant log text:

> Runaway argument?
>   {.508 bar + \frac {(7.4*10^{-3} mol)^{2}*1.408 \frac {L^{2}*bar}{mol^\ETC.
>   ! File ended while scanning use of \frac.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The last line of your `math` environment has an unmatched brace (opens at `.508 bar` and is never closed). While this (and the empty line before "Calculation of...") are the only explicit *errors*, you may want to study some mathematics best practices for typesetting these sorts of things. [The LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments) has a good start, and you can find many resources on this site as well as the broader web.

Comment: `\frac` takes two arguments, like `\frac{\pi}{4}`. But you'll also find that you won't want a single math mode environment, as @PaulGessler said. As it stands now, all your non-math text in the math environment will be stripped of spaces, italicized, extra spaces added around colons, etc.

Comment: In addition to Paul and Mike: Open a command line prompt and type there `texdoc mathmode`. This should open a PDF document with title “Math mode” written by [Herbert](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/) Voß and included in your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 9):

You won't be needing one big math environment for this. Further, it is a good idea to use `siunitx` package for typesetting your units. Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,detect-weight]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\inHg}{inHg}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mmHg}{mmHg}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Molar Mass of Nitrogen\\
Bulb Volume: $\SI{13.7}{\centi\meter^{3}} = \SI{0.2317}{\litre}$\\
Internal bulb pressure: $\SI{0}{\inHg} = \SI{508}{\mmHg} = \SI{0.508}{\bar}$\\
Temperature: \SI{294.2}{\kelvin}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$M = \dfrac{\rho}{P}RT$ \\[0.5\baselineskip]
$\rho = \dfrac{\SI{0.158}{\gram}}{\SI{0.2137}{\litre}} = \SI{0.739}{\gram\per\litre}$ \\[0.5\baselineskip]
$M = \dfrac{\SI{0.739}{\gram\per\litre}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}} * \SI{0.083144}{\litre\bar\per\mole\per\kelvin} * \SI{294.2}{\kelvin} = \SI{35.6}{\gram\per\mol}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
Calculation of Volume by van der Waals Equation with Successive Approximations \\[0.5\baselineskip]
$V = \dfrac{nRT}{P + \dfrac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}} + nb$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$a = \SI{1.408}{\square\litre\bar\per\mol^{2}}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$b = \SI{0.03913}{\litre}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$V \approx \dfrac{nRT}{P} + nb \approx \dfrac{nRT}{P}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$n = \dfrac{m}{M} = \dfrac{\SI{0.158}{\gram}}{\SI{21.35}{\gram\per\mol}} = 7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
$V = \dfrac{7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.083144}{\litre\bar\per\mol\per\kelvin} * \SI{0294.2}{\kelvin}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}} = \SI{0.2138}{\litre}$\\[0.5\baselineskip]
\begin{flalign*}
V &= \dfrac{7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.083144}{\litre\bar\per\mol\per\kelvin} * \SI{294.2}{\kelvin}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}}&& \\
    & \quad + \dfrac{(7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol})^{2}* \SI{1.408}{\square\litre\bar\per\square\mol}} {(\SI{0.2138}{\litre})^{2} + 7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.03913}{litre}} &&\\
&= \SI{0.2137}{\litre}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details you can `texdoc mathmode` `texdoc amsldoc` and `texdoc siunitx` from the terminal.

As a side note, I would also use `\cdot` or `\times` to show multiplication, but not `*`. This, I didn't change in the above example.

Comment: I never noticed the separate `\litre` and `\liter` commands in `siunitx` until now. Or that SI had [three different symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre#SI_prefixes_applied_to_the_litre) for it.

Answer (score 1):

(As has already been pointed out, the immediate reason for the compilation failure is that you're missing a right curly brace after the first `.508 bar` in the final calculation of `V`.)

In addition to using the capabilities of the `siunitx` package to handle the formatting of units, I'd also use an `align*` environment to typeset the sequence of calculations. Using such an environment will free you from having to fine-tune the distances between successive lines via instructions such as `\\[2ex]`. (If you need to allow the insertion of a page break somewhere in the sequence of calculations, insert the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` before `\begin{align*}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,
            detect-weight,
            group-digits=false]
           {siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\inHg}{inHg} % borrowed from Harish's answer...
\DeclareSIUnit{\mmHg}{mmHg}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{}l}
\text{Molar Mass of Nitrogen}\\
\text{Bulb Volume: } \SI{13.7}{\centi\meter^{3}} = \SI{0.2317}{\liter}\\
\text{Internal bulb pressure: } \SI{0}{\inHg} = \SI{508}{\mmHg} = \SI{0.508}{\bar}\\
\text{Temperature: } \SI{294.2}{\kelvin}
\end{array}$

\begin{align*}
M    &= \frac{\rho}{P}RT \\
\rho &= \frac{\SI{0.158}{\gram}}{\SI{0.2137}{\liter}} = \SI{0.739}{\gram\per\liter} \\
M    &= \frac{\SI{0.739}{\gram\per\liter}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}} * \SI{0.083144}{\liter\bar\per\mole\per\kelvin} * \SI{294.2}{\kelvin} = \SI{35.6}{\gram\per\mol}\\
\intertext{Calculation of volume by van der Waals equation with successive approximations}
V &= \frac{nRT}{P + \frac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}} + nb\\
a &= \SI{1.408}{\square\liter\bar\per\mol^{2}}\\
b &= \SI{0.03913}{\liter}\\
V &\approx \frac{nRT}{P} + nb \approx \frac{nRT}{P}\\
n &= \frac{m}{M} = \frac{\SI{0.158}{\gram}}{\SI{21.35}{\gram\per\mol}} = 7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol}\\
V &= \frac{7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.083144}{\liter\bar\per\mol\per\kelvin} * \SI{0294.2}{\kelvin}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}} = \SI{0.2138}{\liter}\\
V &= \frac{7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.083144}{\liter\bar\per\mol\per\kelvin} * \SI{294.2}{\kelvin}}{\SI{0.508}{\bar}} \\
  &\quad + \frac{(7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol})^{2}* \SI{1.408}{\square\liter\bar\per\square\mol}} {(\SI{0.2138}{\liter})^{2} + 7.4*10^{-3}\si{\mol} * \SI{0.03913}{\liter}} \\
 &= \SI{0.2137}{\liter}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```